# Find the determinant of a $4 \times 4$ matrix using row reduction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The original matrix is:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &0  &1 \\ 
3 &3  &3  &9 \\ 
1 & 4 & 1 &4 \\ 
1 & 1 & 2 &0 
\end{bmatrix}

Every time I reduced this to row echelon form, I got $\dfrac{1}{48}$ as the determinant when the actual determinant is $48$. Here are the row operations.

[image]

The rows that I have highlighted are the ones that **change** the determinant since we are changing a row by a factor. All the other operations don't change the determinant and we never switch rows here.

So we get $\det(A) = \dfrac{-1}{3}\times\dfrac{1}{3}\times\dfrac{-3}{16}\times 1 \text{ (entries along diagonal)} = \dfrac{1}{48}$. But the actual determinant is $48$. Where have I went wrong? I did the row operations a couple of times but I am making the same mistake.

Comment: It is the opposite : entries along diagonal  times scalar that you multiplied during the process = determinant.

Comment: Multiplying a single row by a factor of $x$ changes the determinant by multiplication by $x$. So to get the original determinant, you'll have to **divide** by the factor, not multiply it. Hence you'll get 48.

Comment: Note also that the determinant of a matrix where all entries are integers must be an integer, because it is obtained by taking only products and sums.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz why divide? If I have done those scalar multiplication to the row, shouldn't the determinant be the original determinant times these scalars?

Comment: Rather than $\det(A) = \frac{-1}{3}\times\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{-3}{16}\times 1$, it should be $\det(A) \times\frac{-1}{3}\times\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{-3}{16}= 1$. To see why it goes that way and not the other, try with a simpler matrix, like $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we start with a matrix $A$ and perform a row operation of multiplying some row $R_i$ by a non-zero scalar $c$ and get a new matrix $A'$. What is the relation between $\det(A)$ and $\det(A')$? Since the determinant is a multilinear functions of the rows of $A$, we have

$$ \det(A') = c \det(A) \iff \det(A) = \frac{1}{c} \det(A'). $$

If we perform various row operations on $A$, the only operations which change the determinant are the multiplication operations. If we have performed multiplication operations by $c_1,\dots,c_k$ (and maybe other row operations) and arrived to the matrix $A'$, we have

$$ \det(A) = \frac{1}{c_1 \dots c_k} \det(A'). $$

In particular, if you reduced $A$ to an upper diagonal matrix $A'$ whose diagonal entries are $1$ then $\det(A') = 1$ and so

$$ \det(A) = \frac{1}{c_1 \dots c_k}. $$